# On PHP Form submission doesn't post first_name & last_name

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I followed a simple tutorial to make a working for here: http://estrellaprofessional.com/contact.html

I get all the values captured except for the fist_name and last_name.

And the code i use as follows:

```
<?php
$country=$_POST['country'];
$prospect=$_POST['prospect'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$all=
"email: ".$email."\r\n".
"Contact Form Submission ".$subject."\r\n".
"country: ".$country."\r\n".
"prospect: ".$prospect."\r\n".
"first_name: ".$first_name."\r\n".
"last_name: ".$last_name."\r\n".
"message: ".$message."\r\n";

    $mailheaders = "From: $email\r\n"; 
    $mailheaders .= "To: amarkmc@gmail.com\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
        mail($toaddress, $subject, $all, $mailheaders);  
          echo("Thank you $name for your interest in Estrella Professional.  Someone 

from Estrella Professional will be in contact with you soon.  Feel free to continue to browse the site.");  
        die;  
?>
```

Being a noob am not sure what am doing wrong? Someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your HTML form look like?

Comment: Yeah, what @Fluffeh said and also, please show us output of: `echo print_r($_POST);` after your form was sent (put that code in the file you shown us in your question).

Comment: and instead of asigning value for each single input from $_POST object you might better use foreach loop, as with high number of fields it will become tough for you to manage them this way, e.g if(!empty($_POST)){  foreach($_POST as $input_name => $input_value){ 
$$input_name = $input_value; } }

Comment: Check the form which was built by html. I assume you write something in HTML like that, First name: <input type="text" name="first_name"> so check the name value.

Comment: On an unrelated side note (as you said you were new to this anyway), you might want to clean up what your user POSTs, trim() is a good function to check out, and you'll also probably want to wrap the emailing inside an IF, and check if the user is missing any required criteria eg: message is only 2 characters long, telephone number isn't valid etc... Only send an email if the standard of information they are giving, reaches a minimum of what you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the HTML code I can see in the link, you haven't got fields in the form for `first_name` and `last_name`. You only have the following:

```
<input name="name" type="text" style="width: 98%;" class="input-text" />
<br />
```

So either use:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Or make two fields in your form called `first_name` and `last_name` like this:

```
<label>Given Name*</label>
<input name="first_name" type="text" style="width: 98%;" class="input-text" />
<br />
<label>Surname*</label>
<input name="last_name" type="text" style="width: 98%;" class="input-text" />
<br />
```

Comment: Oh my Goodness! Got it fixed. Thanks!